Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
I am trying to do some data preprocessing before it feed into machine learning models.
However, I had error of this
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
Before I did this
    if data[i].dtype == 'object':
        data[i] = data[i].str.strip().str.capitalize()

And it didn't show any error.
When I tried to do
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
for i in data_test.columns:
    if data_test[i].dtype == 'category':
        data_test[i] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data_test[i])

It showed
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_25508\395068224.py in ?()
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
      2 label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
      3 for i in data_test.columns:
----> 4     if data_test[i].dtype == 'category':
      5         data_test[i] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data_test[i])

~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self, name)
   6200             and name not in self._accessors
   6201             and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   6202         ):
   6203             return self[name]
-> 6204         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Any help or direction would be really helpful, thank you!

do you have more than one column with the same name? That would cause your code to return a dataframe instead of a series

Ohhh, yes there do have one I just found out now.

If you have a data frame you need to use dtypes instead of dtype or you can change the column name
